# Insert less than max value in identity column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I deleted some of the records from a table and want to reinsert them from a backup table. The primary key column is identity column and it have larger values than the deleted ones.When I try to insert its throwing error. I cannot reseed the column. Please let me know if it possible in SQL server.

Comment: it's definitely possible. post some of your SQL, and the errors you're getting.

Comment: I don't think you can reseed to a value less than existing maximum and even if you could it would not be a good idea.  Use IDENTITY_INSERT as in the answer from igor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you do this make sure that there are no other processes that inserting into this table or they could receive an error when the `IDENTITY` is disable. Alternatively wrap the whole thing in [transaction with the isolation level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) set to `SERIALIZABLE` to prevent any concurrent changes coming from other processes.

1. Disable the `IDENTITY` on your table/column.
2. Execute your INSERT statements from your backup, be sure you specify the value of the column that was your `IDENTITY` column.
3. Re-enable the `IDENTITY` on your table/column.

Sql:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <your_table> OFF
-- Exceute Inserts
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <your_table> ON
```

**Notes**

You should probably execute your inserts wrapped in a transaction. That way you can roll everything back if there is a failure. You should also not have any conflicts as the identity always increments so re-adding deleted records should not pose a problem. You might want to check your index fragmentation though on the PK once you are done.